removing hidden control characters in filenames
I have a huge number of files spread across a large directory structure that have hidden control characters in their names. ls lists them as, e.g.:
'614.7-4-F1-00-090-007-RozvadØ'$'\302\237'' RP1-List1.pdf'
This eventually causes issues with rsync. What would be a clever way to rename those files by removing those characters?
I think find -name '*[^[:print:]]*' will find all those files. Then sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' should hopefully get rid of those so I am trying
find -name '*[^[:print:]]*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed s/[^[:print:]]//g)"' _{} \;

but it gives
mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory

So I think this might be related to the quoting but I no longer have idea how to correct it. Or maybe, this is not even the correct way to do it.

Why are you using _{} as placeholder for the filename? In my find implementation, it is just {}...

@AdminBee That might be a simple typo in the question. There should be a space after the underscore (and the underscore should ideally be a more descriptive string, like sh).

Could your problem perhaps be solved with the --iconv parameter of the rsync command instead of changing filenames?

Are you sure they are control characters? With find -name '*[^[:print:]]*' I get some valid filenames, just using non-ASCII characters like diacritics.

With zsh:
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*[^[:print:]]*)(#qD)' '$1${2//[^[:print:]]}'

Technically, we could just do:
zmv -n '(**/)(*)(#qD)' '$1${2//[^[:print:]]}'

But having the glob be more selective means less work for zmv. The (#qD) to enable the Dotglob qualifiers is to also consider hidden files like find does by default.
To do it with sed, assuming the GNU implementations of find, sed, mv and xargs:
find . -depth -name '*[^[:print:]]*' -print0 |
  sed -zE 'p;:1;s|[^[:print:]]([^/]*)$|\1|;t1' |
  xargs -ro0n2 mv -Ti --

(though it won't have any of the safeguards of zmv)
Note:

it's important the files be processed depth first (the leaves before the branches they're on) or it won't work properly if there are directories to be renames containing files also to be renamed. zmv does that by default, we add -depth for that here.
only the base names of the files must be modified. To do that with sed we remove one non-printable character followed only by non-/s till the end of the line and repeat.
There's a risk two files will end up with the same name once renamed. zmv will abort before doing anything if that's the case, we use mv -i (and -o for xargs) so the user gets a prompt if a file is going to be overwritten.
mv can be move to or move into depending on whether the target is a directory or not. zmv will check if the destination exists (and aborts if any exists) so it can't be a move into there. We use the -T GNU extension of GNU mv to disable the move into mode.
echo can't be used for arbitrary data.
xargs can't be used reliably without -0 especially with files with funny names.
[...] is a glob operator in the shell so must be quoted there to be passed literally to sed
you have _{} instead of _{}, or better sh {}, which means $0 gets _./path/to/file and $1 gets nothing which explains your error message.
sh scripts even inline scripts can take more than one argument, so you don't need to call one sh per file.
negating a set in standard glob patterns with with [!set], not [^set]. [^set] works in a few find/fnmatch() implementations (including GNU find when on a GNU systems) and a few shells including zsh.
newline is also as valid a character as any in a file name and is not classified as printable. Unless you use the -0 option of GNU sed, sed works on the contents of one line at a time, so won't remove the newline characters.

To fix your approach and avoid GNUisms, that would look rather like:
find . -depth -name '*[![:print:]]*' -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    dir=${file%/*}
    base=${file##*/}
    new_file=$dir/$(
      printf "%s\n" "$base" |
        sed -e "
          :1
          \$!{
            N
            b1
          }
          s/[^[:print:]]//g"
    )
    if [ -e "$new_file" ]; then
      printf>&2 "%s\n" "$new_file already exists"
      ret=1
    else
      mv -i -- "$file" "$new_file" || ret=1
    fi
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +

(untested). Here using sed instead of tr as GNU tr at least doesn't support multi-byte characters, while GNU sed does.
Now, those characters look like they're the result of a bogus transcoding.
$'\302\237' is the visual representation of the UTF-8 encoding of the U+009F control character, so that file name must be UTF-8 encoded text, Ø is U+00D8 (encoded as 0xc3 0x98 in UTF-8)
I note that byte 0xD8 and 0x9F are respectively the ě and č characters in the IBM852 charset and a web search suggests that  rozvaděč is a thing (switchboard in Czech), ibm852 being a charset use in MSDOS for Czech (and possibly still MS Windows like ibm850 still often is in English Windows systems).
So it looks like those file names have been converted to UTF-8 from the wrong charset (iso8859-1 instead of ibm852), and you can get back to the original with:
$ printf '%s\n' '614.7-4-F1-00-090-007-RozvadØ'$'\302\237'' RP1-List1.pdf' |
   iconv -t iso-8859-1 | iconv -f ibm852
614.7-4-F1-00-090-007-Rozvaděč RP1-List1.pdf

Assuming all file names with non-ASCII characters (with bytes greater than 127 / 0x7f / 0177) have been mis-encoded like that, in zsh, you can fix them with:
zmv -n $'(**/)(*[^\1-\177]*)' \
       '$1$(<<<$2 iconv -t iso8859-1 | iconv -f ibm852)'

You can also use convmv twice:
$ convmv --notest -r -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 .
mv "./614.7-4-F1-00-090-007-RozvadØ RP1-List1.pdf"      "./614.7-4-F1-00-090-007-Rozvad؟ RP1-List1.pdf"
Ready! I converted 1 files in 0 seconds.

(0xd8 0x9f happens to be ؟ in UTF-8 but that's a red herring)
$ convmv --nosmart --notest -r -f ibm852 -t utf-8 .
mv "./614.7-4-F1-00-090-007-Rozvad؟ RP1-List1.pdf"      "./614.7-4-F1-00-090-007-Rozvaděč RP1-List1.pdf"
Ready! I converted 1 files in 0 seconds.

